# Open print window in the same tab without changing the content of the current tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm calling this function on a button click that opens a print window, but the content of my page also gets changed to `htmlData`. I don't want to change the content of my page but only change the content of print window which was opened.

Any solutions? Thanks.

```
 print() {

   const WinPrint = window.open(
          " ",
          "_self",
          "left=0,top=0,width=900,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0"
        );
    
    let htmlData =
          "<html><head> <style....</html>";
        WinPrint.document.write(htmlData);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
}
```

Comment: So why are you using `"_self",` as the context target? ["_self: the current browsing context."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)

Comment: Have you ever learned about print stylesheets so you do not have to deal with pop up windows?

Answer (score 0):

You set the window context to `"_self"`. Self targets the current window.

You want `"_blank"` or any other name that is not a [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) that points to the same window.

Comment: Thanks initially both the first two parameters of window.open were blank I checked with blank also but was getting about:blank at the top of the page I tried to modify it but couldn't get the correct result, my only motive is to change the about:blank to any other custom labels and URL should be current URL or blank

Comment: `about:blank` has nothing to do with `"_blank"`, it is the fact you have no page set.